# Need xlrd 0.9x to read from a .xlsx format excel sheet in Windows 8

Tags: python, windows, xlrd

I use Enthought Canopy in Windows 8 which uses python 2.7.
I have written a python script which needs to read from a .xls and/or a .xlsx format excel sheet.

These are the things I have already tried doing but failed:

1. Upgrade xlrd from 0.7x which I use right now to 0.9x
   Couldn't do that because I couldn't figure out how to get the downloaded 0.9.3 file to install.
2. Try to dual boot Ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8. Things got a little complicated and I thought there must be better ways to read a .xlsx file than to run a whole new OS.

I can run Ubuntu 12.04 in a virtual machine if that can get the job done.

Which is the easiest way for me to get my script to read .xlsx on windows 8?

Comment: The latest Enthought Canopy comes with xlrd 0.9.3, according to their Web site.  It also comes with a package manager, to handle updates if needed.